# MySQL update table column based on values from two other tables

Tags: mysql, for-loop, memory, sql-update

I have three tables: Guest, JournalEntry & EmailCore with the following relevant columns

```
JournalEntry (je)
------------------------------
id | guestId | emailId | store


EmailCore (ec)
----------
id | store


Guest (g)
----------
id | store
```

With the following relationships:

```
je.guestId -> g.id

je.emailId -> ec.id
```

I just added the store column on the JournalEntry table with:

```
ALTER TABLE `JournalEntry` ADD `store` int(11) NOT NULL;
```

and I am trying to migrate all of the store data from EmailCore and Guest into JournalEntry with the following rules:

1) If je.emailId is not null then use the store from EmailCore

2) Else use the store from Guest

I know for a fact that for every row in JournalEntry will have a store in either EmailCore or Guest.

With that in mind, I have tried this query:

```
-- Migrate the proper store number to the store column of JournalEntry
-- If present, EmailCore.store has priority
UPDATE JournalEntry je
LEFT JOIN Guest g on g.id = je.guestId
LEFT JOIN EmailCore ec on ec.id = je.emailId
SET je.store = COALESCE(ec.store, g.store);
```

The problem with this query is that it tries to construct a large table built from all three tables (je, ec & g) and I keep running out of memory or the process locks up before it completes and I have to bounce the db cluster. I can get the query to work if I limit the rows to around 0.5 mil. However, JournalEntry contains about 20 mil records.

Can anyone think of a better/faster less memory intensive way to complete this task? Maybe a for-loop/procedure. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your performance issue may be because you have multiple matching rows in `guest` and `email_core`.  But, if there are not many duplicates, then indexes will help the query:

```
create index idx_guest_id_store on guest(id, store);
create index idx_emailcore_id_store on emailcore(id, store);
```

But, if `id` is already a primary key, then that is almost as good.

If you are getting lots of duplicate rows because of the joins, I would first suggest two updates:

```
UPDATE JournalEntry je JOIN
       EmailCore ec
     on ec.id = je.emailId
    SET je.store = ec.store;

UPDATE JournalEntry je JOIN
       Guest g
       on g.id = je.guestId
    SET je.store = g.store;
WHERE je.emailid IS NULL;
```

Then I would simplify these using a subquery:

```
UPDATE JournalEntry je
    SET je.store = (SELECT ec.store
                    FROM EmailCore ec
                    WHERE ec.id = je.emailId
                    LIMIT 1
                   );

UPDATE JournalEntry je
    SET je.store = (SELECT g.store
                    FROM Guest g
                    WHERE g.id = je.guestId
                    LIMIT 1
                   )
    WHERE je.emailid IS NULL;
```